# Paypal lightbox: does not permit cross-origin framing

Tags: javascript, ajax, paypal

I have attempted to go about the use of Paypal Lightbox a bit differently.
I have used a button to trigger an ajax call which then generates the PayKey and if all goes well then triggers the form (from the documentation) to be created and submitted.

When i click the button the lightbox html is created but the content is not loaded into it. Instead i get the error:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dispatch-failed does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

My Code:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

External Script:

```
$("#checkout").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    if(id) { pay(id); }
});

function pay(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'paypal/Pay-Chained.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : "id="+id,
        success : function (data) {
            var info = (JSON.parse(data));
            if (info['Type'] == 'Success') {
                var output = info['URL'].substr(0, 64) + "expType=light&" + info['URL'].substr(64);
                $("body").append('<form action="'+output+'" target="PPDGFrame" class="standard"><input type="submit" id="submitBtn"></form>');
                $("#submitBtn").click();
            } else {
                alert("Error: Please try again or contact support.");
            }
        },
        error : function () {
            alert("Error: Please try again.");
        }
    });
}
```

At the bottom of the buttons page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var embeddedPPFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({trigger: 'checkout'});
</script>
```

I am thinking maybe it has to do with the order things are executed but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be great!

EDIT: I just created a blank page and copied the script from the documentation exactly. I still get the same error. Might it have something to do with server settings? I am running a WampServer with an address like 192.168.1.1/mysite/index.html.